# Close UIAlertview programmatically without timeframe

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am using `UIAlertView` in my Swift project to display messages/current action performed, this is happening when network transaction is taking place. I want to close that `UIAlertView` when I received successful response from API endpoint.

Is there any way to close currently showing alert programmatically or without using timer.

Answer (score 2):

set your alert name in globally and add the following line when you got the response,this will make the alert go away

```
alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for question

Declare `UIAlertview` globally

```
   let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
```

In my case before initiating network transition, Write following block of code:

```
  alert = UIAlertView(title: "MyAlert", message: "Message Body", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: nil,nil)
  alert.show()
```

After getting Successful response, dismiss the UIAlertView:

```
  alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)
```